# loading tabs via ajax to main page

Tags: jquery, ajax

what i need is explaining.
i have one slider in this all li contain product images so i have to show related product images in tabs.(ie 1st images have 3 releted products images than i have to show three tabs and each tabs contain images)

this is done from slider get current li product id and this id by ajax in **get_product.php** page and get related product from database and show in tabs and load to main page back where

```
<div id='tabproduct'></div>
```

my code is and current product id is "5" so

```
function getId(ID5) {   
                var strURL="get_product.php?proid="+ID5;
                var req = getXMLHTTP();
                if (req) {
                    req.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if (req.readyState == 4) {
                            if (req.status == 200) {    
                                    document.getElementById('tabproduct').innerHTML=req.responseText;
                                //alert(req.responseText);                      
                            } else {
                                alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
                            }
                        }               
                    }           
                    req.open("GET", strURL, true);
                    req.send(null);
                }       
            }
```

in ajax page get_product.php with php logic final html like this

```
<div class="tabs">
    <ul class="tab-links">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab1"> product 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">product 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab3">product 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="tab1" class="tab active">
            <p>image 1</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tab2" class="tab">
            <p>image 2</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tab3" class="tab">
            <p>image 3</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and jscript is like

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.tabs .tab-links a').on('click', function(e)  {
        var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');
        jQuery('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();
        jQuery(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
```

if this **tabs html** is call without ajax work fine but when this **tabs html** via ajax, jquery has no effect

please guide me some thing i doing wrong or this is possible or not.

Answer (score 0):

Code inside of `jQuery(document).ready(function(){...})` is exected once the browser finished rendering the page. Note that this does't fire again if you load content via AJAX afterwards.

One way to solve the problem is to attach the event handler after the ajax operation manually:

```
jQuery('#tabproduct .tab-links a').on('click', function(e)  {
    var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    jQuery('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();
    jQuery(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

Put this after the code is inserted into the DOM (where your alert is placed):

```
if (req.status == 200) {    
    document.getElementById('tabproduct').innerHTML=req.responseText;
    //alert(req.responseText);                      
}
```

Comment: hi i have inserted code but no result can you give me another solution when i click on tab no changes only first images shows

Comment: sorry, i forgot the # in `#tabproduct`. I edited my code example.

Comment: Glad to hear. Would be nice if you accepted the answer (click on the check-sign).